# Installation and obtaining the current dfs.name.dir and dfs.data.dir values

Tags: linux, configuration, hadoop, settings, hdfs

I didn't set `dfs.name.dir` and `dfs.data.dir` values in the hdfs-site.xml file aren't set. With what they shall be? And also interestingly what values they accept by default? (how to receive their current values? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value for the `dfs.name.dir` is `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data` and `dfs.data.dir` is  `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data`.

If the value for the `hadoop.tmp.dir` is not set either with -D option or configuration files, the default value is `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`

where `user.name` is the username that you used to login to your system.

For all default values, look at the `core-default.xml, hdfs-default.xml and mapred-default.xml` in the link http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/core-default.xml?av=f

Answer (score 0):

These values default to the "/tmp" directory, if not set in hdfs-site.xml file.

Comment: what they shall be? @Tariq